# Why am I falling through floor near linked_portal_doors?

Tags: portal-2, hammer

I am creating a map for Portal 2 in Hammer and I have a few linked_portal_doors. The floor near some of them makes you fall through. Can someone please tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: Fall through what, exactly? Fall through the portal, fall through the brush entity of the ground, or fall through the level? Can you upload screenshots of the level, in Hammer and/or in-game?